# mysql gap lock compatibility

Tags: mysql, transactions

in [mysql document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-gap-locks) it said

> It is also worth noting here that conflicting locks can be held on a gap by different transactions. For example, transaction A can hold a shared gap lock (gap S-lock) on a gap while transaction B holds an exclusive gap lock (gap X-lock) on the same gap. The reason conflicting gap locks are allowed is that if a record is purged from an index, the gap locks held on the record by different transactions must be merged.

I have a table `users`, the column `id` is primary key

```
mysql> select * from users;
+----+-------+------+
| id | name  | age  |
+----+-------+------+
|  1 | tom   |   21 |
|  2 | jerry |   10 |
|  3 | eric  |   18 |
|  5 | eric  |   17 |
+----+-------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
Sess1 mysql> start transaction;
      mysql> select * from users where name='eric' for update;
+----+------+------+
| id | name | age  |
+----+------+------+
|  3 | eric |   18 |
|  5 | eric |   17 |
+----+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
      
Sess2 mysql> start transaction;
      mysql> select * from users where name='eric' lock in share mode;  -- it's blocking!
```

if gap S-lock and gap X-lock can be hold by different transactions, why `Sess2` is blocked?

Answer (score 0):

The second query:

`mysql1 > select * from users where name='eric' lock in share mode;`

acquired `IS` lock on table and `S` lock on rows with name `eric` so can't update this row by different connection.

So, one transaction has update transaction with exclusive (**IX**) lock and another is in share mode with shared (**S**) lock and based **Table-level lock type compatibility** which is summarized in the following matrix they have conflict and the later transaction must be locked while first transaction is in running.

|  | X | IX | S | IS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **X** | Conflict | Conflict | Conflict | Conflict |
| **IX** | Conflict | Compatible | ***Conflict*** | Compatible |
| **S** | Conflict | Conflict | Compatible | Compatible |
| **IS** | Conflict | Compatible | Compatible | Compatible |

Read following paragraph from [Locking Reads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) for more information.

- `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`

For index records the search encounters, locks the rows and any associated index entries, the same as if you issued an UPDATE statement for those rows. Other transactions are blocked from updating those rows, from doing `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE`, or from reading the data in certain transaction isolation levels. Consistent reads ignore any locks set on the records that exist in the read view. (Old versions of a record cannot be locked; they are reconstructed by applying undo logs on an in-memory copy of the record.)